# Do we have Perl - CPAN like library of Functions in PHP too?

Tags: php, cpan

As we have CPAN Libraries in Perl, do we have similar kind in PHP ? actually am new to PHP and was not sure about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes - [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/) and [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/) essentially serve this function.

Comment: That was the idea with PEAR, but the php-landscape is more fragmented than Perl, so you'll often have to look elsewhere for libraries. PEAR is not as canonical as it could have been.

Comment: "PEAR is not as canonical as it could have been" And imo the lack of a (more) widely accepted repository is a weak point of php.

Comment: PEAR has 544 packages. CPAN has 16782 and number of uploads is raising exponentially. PHP problem is that it does not have concept of module.

Comment: The issue is not PHP's lack of 'module' support - it's that PEAR isn't a free-for-all like CPAN. There are coding standards, you have to get your module approved first, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Watch the http://phpclasses.org

(I found it when looking for Php lib. for image recognizing)